# Accessing a struct field using an int or enum value

Tags: c, struct

I currently use a logging system that uses a tag value to identify the parameter that it will store. The format we are using is the following:
Tag + Time + value.

The next step is to take a logged message and send it to a server using Protocol Buffers to serialize the data.

The protocol buffer .proto file, provides a struct with all the fields each corresponding to a tag in the original logging system.

The problem comes when I need to efficiently read the tag and assign the value to a field in the protocol buffer struct. In essence I would for example like to take in tag 5 and be able to find the field 5 in the struct and write the value.

I know this could be done with switch cases, but we are using around 50 tags so I would like to avoid this solution if possible. I attach an example struct to illustrate the problem.

```
/* Struct definitions */
typedef struct _Profiles {
    int32_t param1;
    int32_t param2;
    int32_t param3;
    int32_t param4;
    int32_t param5;
    int16_t param6;
    int32_t param7;
    uint32_t param8;
    int32_t param9;
    int32_t param10;
    uint32_t param11;
    int32_t time;
/* @@protoc_insertion_point(struct:Profiles) */
} Profiles;
```

The expected result would be that I can store a logged line like the following:
5 1345643 1500 (tag, time, value)

to a protocol buffer struct:

```
profiles.param5 = 1500
profiles.time  = 1345643
```

without the need of 12 switch cases (in this example). Basically, how can I access the 5th declared field of a struct using an integer/enum.

Bare in mind that each field of the struct could potentially have a different type.

Comment: Why you have members `param1` .. `param10` and not array `int32_t param[10]`? Or the names are illustrative.

Comment: In this problem, they are indeed illustrative and could potentially have different types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach would be having pointers to each of the fields as below.

```
int *ptr[11] = {&profiles.param1, &profiles.param2,  &profiles.param3,,,,,, &profiles.param11};
```

And when the message arrives, I will update the field using `ptr`.

```
  *ptr[tag-1] = 1500; //tag-1 because ptr[4] points to profiles.param5
```

Comment: Many thanks for the fast response @kiran . As I understand, all the values pointed to must be ints. How would this work if the struct has floats, strings and different types? I struggle to adapt it to make it work for that. Perhaps the example struct I provide is not the best for the explanation .

Comment: You could use `void *` instead of `int *` and while dereferencing make sure to typecast to actual type. This works only if you know what type to typecast.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on the previous solution by @kiran.

In case you have multiple types then you need to store void pointers. But for typecasting you again need to have a switch case.

This can be avoided in two ways.

1. Store the type along with the data. i.e, store `(tag, type, time, value)`. Then you can have a limited no of conditions for the types.

   ```
   void *ptr[11] = {&profiles.param1, &profiles.param2,  &profiles.param3,,,,,, &profiles.param11};

   switch (type)
   {
       case 0:
           *(char*)ptr[tag-1] = value;
           break;
       case 1:
           *(int*)ptr[tag-1] = value;
           break;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively you can have a map which stores the type of the value

   ```
   void *ptr[11] = {&profiles.param1, &profiles.param2,  &profiles.param3,,,,,, &profiles.param11};
   char typearr[11] = {0,1,0,0....1};  // 0 for char, 1 for int etc

   type = typearr[tag-1];

   switch (type)
   {
      ...
   }
   ```